# SharePoint Framework error : Resource "jquery" not found in loader configuration of manifest for component

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling

I know that this question has already been there, but am raising it because after trying all blogs issue did not get resolved.

Am trying to load non-AMD module having dependency on AMD module. Since its not possible so as suggested in other blogs to make AMD as non-AMD then it can be used as dependency to non-AMD module.

Below is my config json.

```
"jquery":{
  "path":"https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js", 
  "globalName": "jQuery"
},
"jqueryUI":{
  "path":"https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js",
  "globalName": "jQuery",
  "globalDependencies": ["jquery"]
},
```

And, am importing it like this way

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
//import 'jqueryUI';
require('jqueryUI')
```

Where am doing wrong?

Blogs that I read are:-

1. https://blog.mastykarz.nl/sharepoint-framework-client-side-web-parts-jquery-plugins-cdn/
2. https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/336
3. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/add-jqueryui-accordion-to-web-part

Comment: What problem do you have exactly?

Comment: Apology for delay in response. I want to load jQuery first then jQuery UI in my application where am referring url for both libraries from cdn.  And for that, I tried the configurations as given above. But it doesn't work and throw an error as specified in title of question.

So, today I installed the typings of jQuery UI explicitly and mentioned in tsconfig.json and it works!

But still I didn't understand its exact working process. Can it possible for you to point me any specific url which has content in depth?

Thanks in advance!